# Using USB Manager to automatically grant permission

Tags: android

I am making an app that will allow external devices to be controlled through that app. Every time I plug in a device, I get the popup asking for permission to use the device (even if I already granted it permission to use it and checked the box to remember). Is there a way to just automatically allow all devices and never ask for permission? Or maybe a way to short circuit the permission like

```java
private UsbManager mUsbManager;
mUsbManager.hasPermission(device) = true;
```

Comment: What is `mUsbManager` ?

Comment: Sorry, added the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

UsbManager doesn't have the method to grant permission, but you can automatically grant permission if you are using intent filters.

An example of what to add in the Android manifest file and the sample device_filter.xml is described here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html#using-intents